# SASS variables are not working in .scss file

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm having trouble with sass variables. The browser is telling me i am using invalid property values and i can see the code editor is not picking up the variables i am using because it's not colorizing them.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled sass and gulp-sass but that didn't fix the problem and i'm out of ideas. I'm sure it's something really simple.

**Key Facts** 
I am on windows 10 
I installed sass using npm install sass 
i installed gulp-sass using npm install gulp-sass 
I am successfully compiling the .scss file into the .css file 
i am currently trying to create the variables in an .scss file 

This is my .scss file

```
$flx: flex;
$clm: column;
$mpage: 1 0 auto;
$space-between: sb;
$pg1: 100vh;

body {
    display: flx;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: clm;
  }

  main {
    flex: mpage;
  }

  .item-wrap{
    justify-content: sb;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Sass to read your variables, when you call them you have to hang the $ character in front of them, as you did when you declared them.

Example:

```
$flx: flex;
$clm: column;
$mpage: 1 0 auto;
$space-between: sb;
$pg1: 100vh;

body {
    display: $flx;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: $clm;
  }

  main {
    flex: $mpage;
  }

  .item-wrap{
    justify-content: $sb;

  }
```